# Add sum the values stored in HTML5 localstorage

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, local-storage, angular2-localstorage

I have list of data stored in localstorage in one of the ionic-angular app as shown below:

```
Age1 3.5
Age2 4
```

Now i want to add the numbers(Result will be 7.5) and display.

I am trying to use he below code but it is not working

```
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){        
            let key = localStorage.key(i);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem(key));
            this.result +=  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
        }
```

Please suggest where i am doing it wrong.

Comment: What is the object that you save in localstorage? I mean structure?

Comment: Don't need JSON.parse() in ionic 5 and angular 7+

Comment: this.storage.get("key").then((value) => { this.temp = value});

Comment: I have multiple pages. And from each page i am saving the diff. key and diff. value which i have mentioned in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code, I have just removed JSON parse as this is not json data, and split with space to get age as float.

```js
result=0;
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){        
            let key = localStorage.key(i);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem(key));
            data=localStorage.getItem(key).split(" ");
            result +=  parseFloat(data[data.length-1]);}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is appending and not adding the numbers. Value is coming as `undefined3.54`

Comment: @BongaigaonGapps I have updated the code, please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `JSON.parse` use `parseFloat(value)`. And that should work fine.

Comment: `NaN` because you're not getting float convertible value with `localStorage.getItem(key)`.  Make sure you are receiving a float convertible string and use `parseFloat()`. To debug, instead of loops, use a single value, convert it and then figure out. You might be having some alphanumeric values, do proper splitting, or post the output of `console.log` for `console.log(localStorage.getItem(key));`